# How to start location service automatically in Android

Tags: android, location

I want to start location service in background in android.
How to start location service without opening settings?
I don't want alert dialog which will open settings.

Comment: You must need to "ON" location in order to start location service from settings in android device if its not "ON".

Comment: you mean open settings ->On location service

Comment: but i don't want manually..only through code in android

Comment: You can't do this. Location API must be explicitly enabled by user otherwise guys like you could create applications which continuously drain battery charge and also violate users' privacy;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android activate gps with AlertDialog: how to wait for the user to take action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044552/android-activate-gps-with-alertdialog-how-to-wait-for-the-user-to-take-action)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible unless you do it manually. Otherwise you can prompt the user to open Location settings page and turn on from there using any `AlertDialog`